# Doxygen : error variable seen as function

Tags: doxygen

I have in a function the following variable :

```
97 
98     UINT8 Reponse;
99     static UINT8 Initialisation = 0;
100     static DWORD StartTime = 0; //
```

Initialisation is also the name of one function :

```
void Initialisation(void)
```

When I clic on the hyperlink on Initialisation line 99, the block of function void Initialisation(void) is oppened.

Did any of you have an idea of what is appening ?

Thanks you for your help
Jean-Marie

Answer (score 1):

See doxygen's [Known Problems](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/trouble.html):

> Not all names in code fragments that are included in the documentation are replaced by links (for instance when using SOURCE_BROWSER = YES) and links to overloaded members may point to the wrong member. This also holds for the "Referenced by" list that is generated for each function.
>   For a part this is because the code parser isn't smart enough at the moment. I'll try to improve this in the future. But even with these improvements not everything can be properly linked to the corresponding documentation, because of possible ambiguities or lack of information about the context in which the code fragment is found.

and

> Doxygen does not work properly if there are multiple classes, structs or unions with the same name in your code. It should not crash however, rather it should ignore all of the classes with the same name except one.